# Rubiks Cube 4x4x4 Top Layer Issue - One Edge Pair Flipped

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles

[image]

I have trouble with that edge.  Please give algorithm or images  for solutions  for turning  it up so that I can form a cross.

Comment: If you truly want to understand the cube and other permutation puzzles, you need to learn commutators, as explained [in this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096592/21820). Then it is obvious that this is a singe pair swap, which needs a parity fix (e.g. quarter slice turn), after which you have a 5-cycle on the edges and you can also find a 5-cyle on centre-pairs, and each 5-cycle is easily solved using 2 commutators. Of course there are shorter solutions, but they are ad-hoc and require memorization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The algorithm is

> $r \  U^2$ - X - $r \ U^2 \ r\ U^2 \ r' \ U^2\ l \ U^2 \ r' \ U^2\ r \ U^2\ r' \  U^2\ r'$

Where $r$ means you have to turn two layers from the right upwards and $r'$ means downwards, $l$ means you have to turn two layers from the left downwards. and x means you have to turn the whole cube one face upwards.

Initial

[image]

$rU^2$

[image]

$\times$ one face up

[image]

$rU^2$

[image]

$rU^2$

[image]

$r'U^2$

[image]

$lU^2$ remember left down!

[image]

$r'U^2$

[image]

$rU^2$

[image]

$r'U^2$

[image]

$r'$

[image]

> Now you can solve the top layer.

For explanation : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6EUHMQ71nA

Answer (score 1):

Better answer here: https://www.speedcube.us/blogs/speedcubing-solutions/4x4-oll-parity-algorithms

OLL Parity Algorithm 2: r', U2, l, F2, l', F2, r2, U2, r, U2, r', U2, F2, r2, F2

Flips the edge and only the edge. Nothing to solve after that.